# Popover presentation doesn't dim tintColor in iOS8

Tags: ipad, ios8, uipopovercontroller, popover, tintcolor

I wonder if it is a feature rather than a bug, yet on iPad running iOS8 presenting a popover doesn't make the controls of the presenting controller dim. The problem doesn't appear under iOS7. Is there any way of making the behavior consistent throughout the OS versions?

iOS7:
[image: iOS7:]

iOS8:
[image: iOS8:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually fixed in the later versions of iOS8